# Можно ли наложить фильтр или сделать выборку из коллекции объектов?

Tags: java, коллекции

Например:из 
`ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>()` 
выбрать все объекты, где 
`object.getClass().getName().contains("String")`

Java 1.6

Comment: Проект требует версии java 1.6?

Comment: Да, только Java 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для Java 1.6

```
ArrayList<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>(); // тут ваша коллекция
ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object object : objectList){
    if (object.getClass().getName().contains("String")){
        result.add(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, простым перебором коллекции это понятно. Я думал может быть есть какое-то решение типа Guava или Commons Collections. Предполагается большое количество итераций и хотелось бы как-то побороться за производительность. Вот уже даже подумываю об db4o.

Comment: использование сторонних библиотек с предикатами для фильтрации делает код чище, но зачастую не выигрывает по производительности у обычного итерационного метода. Пример: [lambdaJ performance](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/PerformanceAnalysis?ts=1281993389&updated=PerformanceAnalysis)

Comment: Полагаю, что на по ставленый вопрос, как он был сформулирован, ответ дан корректно. Хоть это и не то на что я рассчитывал... :)